# How Can I get the USERID from EMS Server Database

Tags: delphi, ems, rad-studio

I would like to get access to the USERID field in the USERS table of the EMS Database in RAD Studio. I know I could create a query to access the field in the Interbase database. However, I am wondering if there is a built-in function/method available that would return this value similar to the BackendUsers.Users.QueryUserName method.

I have tried to find an example of extracting the USERID from a JSONObject but have been unsuccessful. My experience with REST/JSON is limited but getting better everyday. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I needed by capturing the ID when the EMS User was created with the following code:

```
var BackEndUsers: TUserEntityValue;
    ID: string;

    BackendUsers.Users.SignupUser(DataSet.FieldByName('NAME').AsString,DataSet.FieldByName('USERPASSWORD').AsString,TJSONObject.Create,UserEntityValue);
    ID := UserEntityValue.ObjectID;
```